# How to user member CA identity for hyperledger fabric transactions

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I get this error when I use the member identity to connect to my network, i works fine if i user the admins certificate key from the wallet

im using the node sdk for the application development

> 2020-05-08T12:00:46.815Z - error: [Channel.js]: Channel:myc received discovery error:access denied
>   2020-05-08T12:00:46.843Z - error: [Channel.js]: Error: Channel:myc Discovery error:access denied
>   2020-05-08T12:00:46.927Z - error: [Channel.js]: Channel:myc received discovery error:access denied
>   2020-05-08T12:00:46.928Z - error: [Channel.js]: Error: Channel:myc Discovery error:access denied
>   2020-05-08T12:00:46.928Z - error: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 2 Peers. Last error was Error: Channel:myc Discovery error:access denied

heres my code

```
                    const gateway = new Gateway();
                    await gateway.connect(ccpPath, {
                        wallet,
                        identity:userResult[0].user_identity,
                        // identity: "admin",
                        discovery: {
                          enabled: true,
                          asLocalhost: true
                        }
                      });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found the answer here at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56233118/what-is-wrong-with-my-connectionprofile-json-file and it worked

Answer (score 0):

try to give sudo access to the folder in which your fabric network is residing.

sudo chmod -R 777 directory-of-fabric-network

Comment: this can be done on a ubuntu os yeah? how to do this on a windows?

Comment: Try to set permissions for your fabric network folder using right click on folder->properties ->security